# Facing runtime error in installer signed by install4j in mac OS 10.14.4

Tags: install4j

I am using install4j 8.0.8. So I have used code signing of install4j but facing the below error at runtime on mac os 10.14.4.

So I have created a macOS folder in media so dmg is generated as end output.

cmdline output when I triggered installer after mounting DMG file

abcrn:0510 10.12.5$ sudo /Volumes/CAI/Common\ Agent\ Infra\ Installer.app/Contents/MacOS/JavaApplicationStub -c
Extracting files ...
CodeResources
/Library/Application Support/Seqrite/CAI/.install4j/jre.bundle/Contents/_CodeSignature/CodeResources
Could not create this file. Shall I try again?
Yes [y], Cancel [c]
y
/Library/Application Support/Seqrite/CAI/.install4j/jre.bundle/Contents/_CodeSignature/CodeResources
Could not create this file. Shall I try again?
Yes [y], Cancel [c][image: please attched img which showing error when I trigger it thrugh UI]

Comment: Same installer is working fine on macOS Catalina 10.15.7

Comment: Please try with the latest version of install4j.

Comment: So I can try with the latest evaluation version but anyway it will not help me because I have a license of install4j 8.0.8 it will not work with the latest version. just for information, I am building and signing MAC installer on a windows machine only through install4j.

Comment: The evaluation version can be used for testing.

Comment: Thanks to @ingo so it's working with the latest version also found one internal issue on our site so now it's working on 8.0.8